# text under order details table with condition

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add a text under the order details table in the my account page as shown in the screenshot below but i want this text to be changed to another text if the order status is changed to complete.

Here is what i use to show the text but i cant make it conditional to change the text to another text if the status changed from any status to complete.

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table', 'action_order_details_after_order_table', 10, 4 );
function action_order_details_after_order_table( $order, $sent_to_admin = '', $plain_text = '', $email = '' ) {
    // Only on "My Account" > "Order View"
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'view-order' ) ) {
        printf( '<p class="custom-text">' .
        __("To cancel your license within the 30 day trial period click on %s" ,"woocommerce"),
        '<strong>"' .__("Refund my entire order", "woocommerce") . '"</strong>.</p>' );
    }
}
```

All i need is to change this message to another message when the order status is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your above codes with follows -

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table', 'action_order_details_after_order_table', 10, 4 );
function action_order_details_after_order_table( $order, $sent_to_admin = '', $plain_text = '', $email = '' ) {
    // Only on "My Account" > "Order View"
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'view-order' ) ) {
        if( $order->get_status() == 'completed' ){ // for completed status
            printf( '<p class="custom-text">' .
        __("Your order completed message goes here %s" ,"woocommerce"),
        '<strong>"' .__("Refund my entire order", "woocommerce") . '"</strong>.</p>' );
        }elseif($order->get_status() == 'cancelled'){ // for cancelled status
           printf( '<p class="custom-text">' .
        __("Your order cancelled message goes here %s" ,"woocommerce"),
        '<strong>"' .__("Refund my entire order", "woocommerce") . '"</strong>.</p>' );
        }else{ // for rest statuses
            printf( '<p class="custom-text">' .
        __("To cancel your license within the 30 day trial period click on %s" ,"woocommerce"),
        '<strong>"' .__("Refund my entire order", "woocommerce") . '"</strong>.</p>' );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested it but it doesn't function as it should be only the first message that appears even if the order is completed or at any other status.

Comment: Can you please check what order status returning from `$order->get_status()`

Comment: I found the issue changed the status from 'wc-completed' to 'completed', and it worked fine now reflecting the 2 messages is that change ok ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. And can you please mark this as approved answer.

Comment: Sure, but can i have another condition is that when order is canceled it appears a third message rather than those 2 ?. i'm trying but i couldn't reach a solution

Comment: @MagedMohamed, I just updated my answer. Please check.